# How is RxJS operator "repeat" implemented?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I was reading the code from RxJS from [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/retry.js) and [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/retrywhen.js) but it depends on many other parts of the library and I can't extract what the idea behind its implementation is. I'm very curious about how it works internally. How can it repeat the `Observable` from the beginning again? For example, here:

```
Rx.Observable.of(2, 4, 5, 8, 10)
    .map(num => {
        if(num % 2 !== 0) {
            throw new Error('Odd number');
        }
        return num;
    })
    //Several other operators later...
    .retry(3)
    .subscribe(
        num => console.log(num),
        err => console.log(err.message)
    );
```

How can it know the beginning of the `Observable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Re-edited answer

Relevant sources for the current version of RxJS are here :

`repeat` is defined here :

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/repeat.ts

```
export function repeat<T>(count: number = -1): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      return empty();
    } else if (count < 0) {
      return source.lift(new RepeatOperator(-1, source));
    } else {
      return source.lift(new RepeatOperator(count - 1, source));
    }
  };
}

class RepeatOperator<T> implements Operator<T, T> {
  constructor(private count: number,
              private source: Observable<T>) {
  }
  call(subscriber: Subscriber<T>, source: any): TeardownLogic {
    return source.subscribe(new RepeatSubscriber(subscriber, this.count, this.source));
  }
}

class RepeatSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
  constructor(destination: Subscriber<any>,
              private count: number,
              private source: Observable<T>) {
    super(destination);
  }
  complete() {
    if (!this.isStopped) {
      const { source, count } = this;
      if (count === 0) {
        return super.complete();
      } else if (count > -1) {
        this.count = count - 1;
      }
      source.subscribe(this._unsubscribeAndRecycle());
    }
  }
}
```

And the `lift` function is defined here :

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts

```
  lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
    const observable = new Observable<R>();
    observable.source = this;
    observable.operator = operator;
    return observable;
  }
```

---

### Conclusion (as per my modest understanding, please don't hesitate comment / correct me)

`repeat(n)` just recursively create copies of the same observable;it just re-subscribes the next copy on the completion of the previous one. It emits a 'completed' event when the last one is completed.

---

### Original answer

To simply answer your basic question :

> How can it know the beginning of the Observable?

Without diving into details, because it "wraps" / "acts on" all the previous Observables, so to say.

And actually, every operator do that! (act on the whole chain behind them)

Don't forget that when you chain/pipe operators, you get a new Observable that corresponds to the whole action from the beginning.

**Operators on Observable return a new Observable, so any new operator applied will be applied on this new "bigger" Observable**

---

Observable1.map(...) returns a new Observable2 corresponding to the whole stream.

Observable2.repeat() repeats the whole.

---

EDIT

I'm not very savvy, so pardon me in advance if I'm wrong, but I guess the core of the implementation is here :

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/repeatproto.js

which is :

```
observableProto.repeat = function (repeatCount) {
  return enumerableRepeat(this, repeatCount).concat();
};
```

Which seems to mean that it basically `concat` n times the same observable.

`repeat(3)` will `concat` 2 times the same observable with itself.

```
let repeated$ = Observable.from([1,2,3]).map(x => x*2).repeat(3);
```

is equivalent to

```
let myObs$ = Observable.from([1,2,3]).map(x => x*2);
let repeated$ = myObs.concat(myObs).concat(myObs);
```

Comment: Can you show your idea with some code? Check [this](https://medium.com/@fknussel/a-simple-observable-implementation-c9c809c89c69) post about `Observable` implementation, specially the implementation of `map`. I think it's the way RxJS operators work in general, and the `Observable` they return isn't for the entire sequence (it's a new one). But that approach could not work for `repeat`.

Comment: @amedina I have updated my answer, with a link to a maybe more relevant part of the source code (not completely sure, though).
But to me, `repeat(n)` does basically a `concat` n-1 times with the same observable.

Comment: also, it seems that the repo you and I linked here is not the current one. see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/

Comment: Yes, I see I made a mistake linking the wrong repo. I read your answer and now I understand how it works. Thanks ;)